# Simple query in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with Firebase in Swift and I see that there are more people in the same boat. My idea here is to retrieve the score of each player.
Firebase db is like this:

[image]

Which is on the root reference (`dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`)
My code is doing this:

```
dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "score").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        for child in snap.children{
            print(child)
        }
    }
```

Which is generating these messages in terminal:

```
Snap (zfUNewjOCsQ5VCtSLFXSXLSFXtJ3) {
    addedByUser = "julio@gmail.com";
    score = 100;
}
Snap (yfJqO65qCwTTlgzrcw1ovmPgZ6l2) {
    addedByUser = "oswaldo@gmail.com";
    score = 1000;
}
```

How to get on the score so the message printed in terminal be like:

100

1000

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use `childSnapshotForPath` to get to the score:

```
dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "score").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    for child in snap.children{
        print((child as AnyObject).childSnapshot(forPath: "score").value)
    }
}
```

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-childsnapshotforpath

Comment: correct answer, the only thing that Xcode complained is to cast as AnyValue

>>    print((child as AnyObject).childSnapshot(forPath: "score").value)

Comment: Thanks for that, I updated the code in my answer. Swift casting is still a magic incantation to me.